# Google Firebase user.PhotoURL doesn't Change After Upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, photo, user-profile

I've been trying to figure out how to update the user photo after uploading it to Google Firebase. The user photo uploads to Firebase, however doesn't chance after uploading. Only it changes when the page is refreshed.

Is there a way to refresh the user profile photo without refreshing the whole page?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth, upload } from "./firebase";

export default function Profile() {
  const currentUser = useAuth();
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [photoURL, setPhotoURL] = useState("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png");

  function handleChange(e) {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setPhoto(e.target.files[0])
    }
  }

  function handleClick() {
    upload(photo, currentUser, setLoading);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser?.photoURL) {
      setPhotoURL(currentUser.photoURL);
    }
  }, [currentUser])

  return (
    <div className="fields">
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button disabled={loading || !photo} onClick={handleClick}>Upload</button>
      <img src={photoURL} alt="Avatar" className="avatar" />
    </div>
  );
```

*Code is taken from LogicismX GitHub page.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on what the upload() function does, you should include it but anyway:

Reading the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) might help, as you'll see there, after the app initialisation you want to export the firestore database as so

```
const app = initialiseApp(firebaseConfig)
export const db = getFirestore(app)
```

Then, in your file where you're trying to render the image, you should change your "read" function to onSnapshot(), this will run every time there's a change in said document in the database, only re-rendering whatever stateful variables you're making change per shapshot

here's an example:

```js
import {onSnapshot, doc} from 'firebase/firestore'

import { db } from './firebaseConfig'

...

onSnapshot(doc(db, '<your-collection-name>', '<your-doc-name>', (snapshot) => {
  setPhotoUrl(snapshot.data().photoURL)
}
```

Comment: Hey Martiwg, thank you so much for your answer. I think real-time listeners are for Cloud Firestone. But here the photoURL method uses somewhere called Storage in Firebase. And I'm not sure how I can add a listener to Storage when there is a change occur. Rather than fixing up this issue, is it possible to solve it with React functions, like re-rendering the component?